# Swift IOS: How to add to an Array of List using user input?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The end goal is to display a table view controller made up of a model and some properties. The model is an array of list, where the list are the properties. An add bar button item takes user to another view controller with several text fields. The text fields correlate with the properties in array's list.
The problem is I can not add the textfield input to the table view controller.
Outlets are connected. Segues are working. Data is being accepted. Just not transferring to Country array.

Aforementioned Tableviewcontroller:

```
public var countries: [Country] = [

    Country(flag: "", name: "United States of America", region: "North America", population: "328.2m"),
    Country(flag: "", name: "Ethiopia", region: "Horn of Africa", population: "105m"),
    Country(flag: "", name: "Greece", region: "South Eastern Europe", population: "10.77m"),
    Country(flag: "", name: "Kyrgystan", region: "Central", population: "6.2m"),
    Country(flag: "", name: "Vatican City", region: "Europe", population: "1000"),
    Country(flag: "", name: "Japan", region: "Northwestern Ring of Fire", population: "126.3m"),
    Country(flag: "", name: "South Sudan", region: "North Africa", population: "11.6m")]
```

My attempt to transfer data in addviewcontroller:

```
   @IBAction func submitCountryTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    newCountry = (Country(flag: "\(flagTextfield!.text!)", name: "\(nameTextfield!.text!)", region: "\(regionTextfield!.text!)", population: "\(popTextfield!.text!)"))
    countries.append(newCountry)
    print("\(flagTextfield!.text!) \(nameTextfield!.text!) has been added")
    }
```

Comment: You need to reload tableview after append new element.

Comment: Have a variable to receive a Country object at the forwarding view controller.

Comment: @NikunjGangani does the reload function go under the IBAction?

Comment: @Eltomato I though the variable newCountry was receiving Country object. Can you elaborate?

Comment: What is `countries`?  Is `AddViewController` a different view controller to your table view?  How is *this* countries related to the array for your table view?  ie. How do you update the array in your tableview controller?

Comment: @Paulw11 countries is the name of array in the tableview controller file. Yes, addViewController is separate view and file with textfield for user input. properties are suppose to be entered so a country is added to array. I'm having trouble relaying the information to the table view controller displaying all countries.

Comment: How do you move back to your table view controller?  Unwind segue? If so you can use that to access the new item.   Otherwise you can use a delegation pattern or closure

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the best practice for transferring user input information from child controller  to a parent table view controller? I attempted to use protocol delegate but information will not transfer to parent class extension.

Answer (score 0):

if countries is the dataSource of the table this should help

```
@IBAction func submitCountryTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    newCountry = (Country(flag: "\(flagTextfield!.text!)", name: "\(nameTextfield!.text!)", region: "\(regionTextfield!.text!)", population: "\(popTextfield!.text!)"))
    countries.append(newCountry)
    print("\(flagTextfield!.text!) \(nameTextfield!.text!) has been added")

    tableView.reloadData() // This is necessary
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations.

Every ! Is a potential crash. I count 10 or so. Download Apple’s Swift book, learn how to use “if let”. Your users will thank you.

The way you use string interpolation is horrendous. Safe:

```
If let flag = flagTextField?.text, let name = nameTextField?.text, … {
    Create new country and add it
} else {
    Handle error without crashing
}
```

Take the opportunity to learn about the guard statement.